# Facebook Unity SDK login permission request pop up for authorized user

Tags: authentication, permissions, unity-game-engine, authorization, facebook-unity-sdk

I've followed through the InteractiveConsole and FriendsSmash example in Unity and learnt how to request permissions during login and get the friend list of the user.

But there's one little problem bothering me a lot.
When `FB.Login("email,user_birthday", LoginCallback)` is called for an authorized user. The user will be redirected to the Facebook page saying "You have already authorized App-Name".

I'm thinking to only call `FB.Login("",LoginCallback)` to every user, and then use the `FB.API` to check if the correct permissions exist, and after that call the original FB.Login method. However, this doesn't seem a very wise way to do this to me.

I did a bit of research but still can't seem to find a nice way to solve this. Can anyone please help me out on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have status=true in your FB.Init(), it should come back with login info if the user is logged in.  You can then use FB.API() and do your permissions check.

Answer (score 0):

I had PlayerPrefs.DeleteAll being called for testing purposes. I found that it was removing the Facebook data so it wasn't authorising on initialisation.

Make sure you don't call PlayerPrefs.DeleteAll()